# Simple image editing service with API

Tags: web-services, image, api

I have been using [Snipshot's API](http://snipshot.com/services/) to provide simple image editing inside a web application. Recently they started injecting ads into the page and aren't providing anyway to remove them, even for paid accounts.

So, I'm looking for another service. Key features would be that it is simple, easy, and light on any external branding. [Picnik](http://www.picnik.com/info/api) is out there, but it is pretty heavy-weight and heavily branded. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you have, but just in case: have you tried emailing the snipshot people and telling them that you're a paying customer and the ads are a deal-breaker and you're about to go elsewhere, is there any way you can remove them e.g. pay a bit more, etc.?

Comment: Yep, I've done that. This was the response, "This is something we may add soon. Stay tuned..." I asked where to stay tuned (they have no blog or twitter account afaik) and received no response :( I'm now a Picnik user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Picnik is the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

[Aviary](http://developers.aviary.com/featherapi) looks pretty good, too.

Answer (score 1):

Picnik is now offline, but there is a Picnik compatible API at picmonkey.com.

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1OhlOYcCvJiV44c13XpDx0HJV3UArKgRya3lq_Ahr5T0